# How to add line breaks after every nth instance of a delimiter in perl

Tags: text-processing, perl

I am looking to write a script that will open a file data.txt and add a line break after every nth instance of the "|" delimiter, so that each line contains one observation with all four variables. Basically splitting up and reshaping a single line from wide to long. Thanks for your help.

Input:

```
a1|b1|c1|d1|a2|b2|c2|d2|a3|b3|c3|d3|a4|b4|c4|d4
```

Output:

```
a1|b1|c1|d1|   
a2|b2|c2|d2|   
a3|b3|c3|d3|  
a4|b4|c4|d4
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?\|){4}\K/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

### Using Sed:

Portably:

```
sed -e 's/|/&\
/4;P;D' file
```

If you are using GNU Sed, you can use the nonstandard `\n` to represent a newline character in the replacement pattern:

```
sed -e 's/|/&\n/4;P;D' file
```

---

The `s` command inserts a newline after the fourth `|` in the pattern space.

The `P` command prints up to the first newline from the pattern space.

The `D` command deletes up to the first newline from the pattern space.

If there was no substitution made (less than four `|` characters in the pattern space), the pattern space won't contain any newlines—so the `P` command will be printing the *entire* pattern space, and the `D` command will delete the entire pattern space, and then the next line from the file will be read in and the loop started over.

Answer (score 1):

tr and paste, not your exact output

```
tr '|' '\n' <file | paste -d'|' - - - -
```

```
a1|b1|c1|d1
a2|b2|c2|d2
a3|b3|c3|d3
a4|b4|c4|d4
```

awk

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -v n=4 '{for (i=n+1; i<=NF; i+=n) $i = "\n" $i; print}' file
```

```
a1|b1|c1|d1|
a2|b2|c2|d2|
a3|b3|c3|d3|
a4|b4|c4|d4
```